# External SharePoint site working internally

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, dns

we have a SP site hosted internally in our office. its like sharepoint.sharepoint.co.uk
as its hosted internally you can obviously get this site by going to server1 as server1 is the sharepoint.sharepoint.co.uk

I want our sharepoint still to work in the situation of losing our internet connection.

so I have created a DNS zone on our server for sharepoint.sharepoint.co.uk with a pointer to the server1 192.168.100.240

this seems to work, internet off and I can still get to the SP site.

our sharepoint company say there must be something wrong as when logging into SP it keeps prompting for username and password even though previously you told it to remember it.
its also added to trusted sites zone. it prompts for server1 not sharepoint.sharepoint.co.uk so they think this DNS zone isn't working properly.

help

Comment: it needs to be added to the local intranet zone. Also, why not use an alternate access mapping to an intranet zone? You should have the sharepoint.sharepoint.co.uk AAM as the default zone.

Comment: alternate access mappings? how would I do this.

Comment: pic is of server1 alternate mappings![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dNLQR.png)

Comment: Edit Public URLs -> Change Default to your sharepoint.sharepoint.co.uk, and change the server1 to your intranet zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be added to the local intranet zone. Also, why not use an alternate access mapping to an intranet zone? You should have the sharepoint.sharepoint.co.uk AAM as the default zone. The default should be the sharepoint.sharepoint.co.uk if you want it to be the most used way to access the site. I don't know what all it is tied to, I would change it afterhours and test, then if all is well, you can keep the change, otherwise you should be ok. Usually Search is most tied to the AAM internally.